# How to access asp object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, tags

I wanted to know if there is a way to access to asp objects in the code behind, but without using the object in itself ?

Let say i have an asp Page in which i have this tag :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In my code behind i can access to this object using : this.test. But i would like to access it in an other way. Something like :

```
 this.Objects["test"]
```

Because I'm parsing an xml document in which i have all my asp objects, and then i want to do some processing on it (set Visible to true ... )

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Found the answer. I'm using SharePoint, so i have to set the context. I can't do

```
this.FindControls
```

so i Added :

```
Control context = this.Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain");
```

And i use :

```
context.FindControl();
```

Comment: You should move your text with the answer from your question into its own answer.  Then you should accept your own answer after the 2 day limit.  That's the standard practice.

Comment: Yeah I know, but i can't answer to myself for the six next hours ...

Comment: Sorry, I was unaware of the 8 hour restriction for user with reputation < 100 self-answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
this.Controls["control"];
```

Comment: Hey, it's not working, you have to use int index when using Controls[]

Answer (score 1):

When you're handling serverside controls you could access them using Page.FindControl(controlName):

```
this.Page.FindControl("txtPageSam").Visible = false;
```

Comment: In fact it's not working. 
It returns null
Is it possible that it's because i'm using Multiview ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ((TextBox) this.FindControl("test")).Visible = true;
```

Comment: If your text box is inside some another control, you'll have to use Findcontrol method of that control . at page lavel that textbox can not be recognized by id "test".